# Gradle wont sync after update from Android Studio 0.54 to 0.81 "NoSuchMethodError"

Tags: gradle, android-studio, nosuchmethoderror

I manually updated my Android Studio by replacing the old files with the ones that you can can download from the Google website, since an automatic update was not possible. Before the upgrade my Android Studio was version 0.54 I believe and after the upgrade it is 0.81.

Upon first start I get a gradle sync error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: Failed to set up Android modules in project '(my app)': com.android.builder.model.Dependencies.getJavaLibraries()Ljava/util/Collection;
```

Since before the upgrade my gradle files synced fine, I don't believe my gradle configuration is wrong.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

It is caused by a conflict of `<Android Studio Dir>/plugins/android/lib/builder-model-0.x.x.jar` files.

Either do a clean install of `0.8.x`

or

Delete the old `builder-model-0.x.x.jar`

Comment: had the same problem updating from 0.6.0 to 0.8.1. This worked for me